# How to create "disabled" for an anchor tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the `a` element to be disabled, but I can't seem to add `disabled: true`. How could this be achieved?

```
function x() {
  var audioBtn = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'sound btn btn-primary'
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
  return audioBtn;
}
```

Comment: Links do not recognize the disabled property.  Form fields do.

Comment: The following: You could implement "disabled" or "required" on an input field. Is this possible with anchor or buttons?

Comment: Buttons, yes.  Links, no

Comment: Please use the search: [`[javascript] disable link`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+disable+link)

Comment: You can use `return false` on a link to simulate the disabled property.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `disabled` attribute for the `<a>` element. However you can still create a link that with a disabled behavior and styling thru a combination of custom data attribute and CSS styling.

**HTML**

`<a data-disabled="true"></a>`

**jQuery**

```
var btn = $('a');
btn.attr('data-disabled', true);
```

**CSS**

```
a[data-disabled="true"] {
    pointer-events: none;
    color: gray; 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The `disabled` attribute applies to form controls like `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc.
- `pointer-events: none` isn't effective against key events (see link #2).
- Disable a link by its `href` value. This is the best way because it can still be registered to listen for a click event unlike `pointer-events:none` (see link #3 and #4).

---

### Demo

```js
var lnx = document.links;

lnx[1].style.pointerEvents = "none";

lnx[2].href = "#/";

lnx[3].href = "#/";

function markText(e) {
  e.target.style.background = "rgba(255,200,0,0.6)";
  return false;
}
```

```css
code,
kbd {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

li {
  line-height: 2;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href='https://example.com'>This link is the control, it should function</a></li>

  <li><a href='https://example.com'>Set CSS property <code>pointer-events:none</code> is not completely effective since user can use keys like <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd></a></li>

  <li>

    <a href='#/'>Assigned <code>"#/"</code> for <code>href</code> value is very effective</a></li>

  <li>
    <a href='#/' onclick="var e=event; markText(e, this);">
      This link is link #3 with an attribute onclick event and a callback function</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function x() {
  var audioBtn = $('<a class="sound btn btn-primary"/>').html('test<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
  return audioBtn;
}
$("body").append(x());
```

```css
.sound {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```